# ArrayList<E> should be parameterized

Tags: arraylist

im trying to follow a tutorial to make a scrolling shooter game in java. However i keep getting this error. I have tried so many things and i can't get it to work!

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong with this code?

```
public class PhysicsSystem {

private ArrayList bodies;

public PhysicsSystem() {
bodies = new ArrayList();
}

public void addBody(PhysicsBody body) {
bodies.add(body);
}

public void removeBody(PhysicsBody body) {
bodies.remove(body);
}

public void update(float delta) {
for (PhysicsBody body : bodies)
body.physicsUpdate(delta);
}
}
```

Comment: ArrayList can hold generic data. You should parameterize the list
`private ArrayList<PhysicsBody> bodies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by error, you mean a warning.

Change

```
private ArrayList bodies;
bodies = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
private ArrayList<PhysicsBody> bodies;
bodies = new ArrayList<PhysicsBody>();
```